# Некорректный запуск "npm init -y" через VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

В терминале VS Code прописываю **"npm init -y"** для создания файла **package.json**. Файл создается, но в нем присутствует **только ключ "description"**.
Где остальные ключи? В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо за конструктивный ответ.

[image: Скрин VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо отметить, что "npm init -y" прописывал впервые в терминале VS Code. Когда получил файл package.json с одним ключом - "description", то остальные необходимые ключи и значения ввел в ручную.

После этого **во всех** проектах при вводе "npm init -y" необходимые ключи **появляются автоматически**.

[image: Скрин из VS Code]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)